# Apache beam on Python: TypeError: Receiver() takes no arguments

Tags: python, apache-beam

I am trying to learn apache beam on Python but none of my examples are working.

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

options = PipelineOptions()
p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
input_filename = "./data/kinglear.txt"

p | beam.io.ReadFromText(input_filename)

result = p.run()
```

results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Projects/Perm/PythonPOC/Beam/Main.py", line 10, in <module>
    result = p.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\pipeline.py", line 416, in run
    self._options).run(False)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\pipeline.py", line 429, in run
    return self.runner.run_pipeline(self, self._options)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\direct\direct_runner.py", line 135, in run_pipeline
    return runner.run_pipeline(pipeline, options)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\portability\fn_api_runner.py", line 389, in run_pipeline
    default_environment=self._default_environment))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\portability\fn_api_runner.py", line 396, in run_via_runner_api
    return self.run_stages(stage_context, stages)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\portability\fn_api_runner.py", line 478, in run_stages
    stage_context.safe_coders)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\portability\fn_api_runner.py", line 774, in _run_stage
    result, splits = bundle_manager.process_bundle(data_input, data_output)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\portability\fn_api_runner.py", line 1811, in process_bundle
    part, expected_outputs), part_inputs):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 586, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 432, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\utils\thread_pool_executor.py", line 42, in run
    self._future.set_result(self._fn(*self._fn_args, **self._fn_kwargs))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\portability\fn_api_runner.py", line 1811, in <lambda>
    part, expected_outputs), part_inputs):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\portability\fn_api_runner.py", line 1747, in process_bundle
    result_future = self._worker_handler.control_conn.push(process_bundle_req)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\portability\fn_api_runner.py", line 1173, in push
    response = self.worker.do_instruction(request)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\worker\sdk_worker.py", line 291, in do_instruction
    request.instruction_id)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\worker\sdk_worker.py", line 317, in process_bundle
    bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\worker\bundle_processor.py", line 675, in process_bundle
    data.transform_id].process_encoded(data.data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\worker\bundle_processor.py", line 146, in process_encoded
    self.output(decoded_value)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\worker\operations.py", line 259, in output
    cython.cast(Receiver, self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Shadow.py", line 165, in cast
    return type(*args)
TypeError: Receiver() takes no arguments
```

I haven't been able to run any example given on any forum, all are resulting in the same error. Not sure what needs to be done to fix it, I am new to Apache beam.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, what Python version are you using?

I'm not exactly sure if it is the python version or the environment that is having the issue, but I resolved this issue by creating a new environment (for my case using `conda`) with python version 3.5.6, and re-installed `apache-beam`. No issues with the code.

---

*Edit - Issue appears to be coming from Cython, there are incompatibilities between the 2 packages. Uninstalling Cython resolves the issue apparently. Issue raised with Apache Beam team - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-9324

Comment: I have tested this on both 2.7 and 3.7, the only difference with 2.7 is that the execution results in `TypeError: object() takes no parameters`; compared to `TypeError: Receiver() takes no arguments` with 3.7

Comment: I realized there's some form of incompatibility of apache beam with Cython, I got the same issue after installing Cython, and after uninstalling Cython it works fine. Time to raise an issue with apache beam

Comment: Also just had this problem while trying to use PyFlink v1.12.0 Table API with ScalarFunction and TableFunction. Already using a separate Anaconda virtualenv for  PyFlink; however, PyFlink and Beam are installed with pip install apache-flink. Uninstalled cython et al with conda remove cython cython-blis cytoolz and PyFlink ScalarFunction works as it should. There were a lot of inconsistencies in the virtualenv that were fixed with the removal of the cython packages. Hope this helps others.

Comment: `pip install -U apache-beam` cleared it for me (python3.9).

Answer (score 0):

Issue still exists in Apache Beam. An alternate solution is to use [`virtualenv`](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/) for `DirectRunner`. A brief tutorial is already available at [apache beam documentation](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-py/). Creating the virtualenv does not automatically load CPython and hence avoids the error.